# Use enumerations in JPA Query

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to use JPA to update an entity property which is an enumeration in my domain model, and I can't make it work.

I have the following entities:

```
public class A {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "status")
    private Status status;

}

public class Status {

    @Id
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private StatusId id;

    public enum StatusId {

        B, C, D, E, F

    }

}
```

and this JPA repository:

```
public interface ARepository extends JpaRepository<A, Long> {

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query("UPDATE A SET status = ?2 WHERE id = ?1")
    void updateStatus(Long id, Status.StatusId status);

}
```

Executing this method throws the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [B] did not match expected type [com.***.Status (n/a)]
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: void updateStatus(@Param("id) Long id, @Param("status") Status.StatusId status);

Comment: @JoopEggen well, obviously that is not the only column in the entity. I just put the required ones for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says:

> Parameter value [B] did not match expected type [com.***.Status

and in your query you are effectively trying to assign an object of type  **Status.StatusId**  to a field of type **Status**

You should try to change the query to something like this:

UPDATE A SET **status.id** = ?2 WHERE id = ?1

Comment: wow, now that you state that, it is so obvious... Got to read more carefully. Thanks!